# Filemaker: counting similar values relational tables/ summary results calculation

Tags: filemaker

I'm doing some data management for a friend's campaign and i'm 100% self taught in file maker which pretty much means I lack a basic understanding of most things. The biggest issue I have is with relational tables. In one table I have all voter information.

How do I make a relationship between the two tables where `Geolocation_Address:$ward` is checked against the master list of `_wards_divisions_2:$ward`? Depending on that ward, I need it to refer to the matching field that contains the appropriate list of divisions. I then need to match `Geolocation_Address` to the master list of `_wards_divisions_2:$divisions`.

The table `Geolocation_Address` has the `Geolocation_Address:$ward` and `divisions` listed for each and every voter as well as the fields `VoterName` and `Already Voted`. The Table `_wards_divisions_2` has the master list of all wards and divisions within that said district.

What I'm trying to do is create a layout that gives a live view of the total count of registered voters. It also must display the live total count of voters with `"Supporter"` selected in my `Geolocation_Address:$Support Level`field out of overall `"Supporter"s` from that same field and table. Entries in the `Geolocation_Address:$Already Voted` field selected as`Yes` also need to be displayed for each ward and division out of all of the people that have `No` selected in the same field. We need to be able to see live updates of people that voted in each designated ward and division as that information is being updated by other machines running filemaker go. It's supposed to track how we are doing with our GOTV efforts so that we can send our van fleet to those designated areas. How would I do this?

What I would like to see is something that will give me live updates based on the counts of similar records. I want to have a live layout that will update the `supporter` numbers, the `already voted` numbers. I'd like to see exactly how I should relate my two tables as well as how I can create those types of calculations or scripts without typing in every combination.

Comment: I can't make head or tails of your question. Please describe (a) the real-world entities your solution is supposed to track, and (b) the result you would like to see. And don't use abstract names like Table1. -- P.S. if you're using FileMaker, why have you tagged your question with PHP, JQuery and MySQL?

Comment: It's my first time posting to stack overflow. I think I updated everything correctly.